# How to get the maximum value of a column of a MySQL table, in PHP land, using the WordPress API

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is becoming a real headache for me. All I need in PHP land is the maximum `id` from a table named `work_carousels`. Running

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM work_carousels
```

straight from the command line in phpMyAdmin returns

```
   MAX(id)
   -------
     12
```

and all I need is that number `12` (or whatever it happens to be at the moment) in my PHP! The [WordPress API for interacting with the database](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) shows me that I should be using

```
$wpdb->get_results
```

to get a PHP object corresponding to the results of the query. I've tried

```
$resultObj = ($wpdb->get_results('SELECT MAX(id) FROM work_carousels'));
$lastAddedCarouselId = $resultObj->MAX(id);
```

and that didn't work, caused an internal server error. I've also tried

```
$lastAddedCarouselId = ($wpdb->get_results('SELECT MAX(id) FROM work_carousels'));
```

and that didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: `$resultObj->MAX(id);` would be trying to call the function `MAX` on the `$resultObj`. Instead try aliasing that to a usable name in the query: `SELECT MAX(id) as max_id FROM work_carousels`, then you may be able to access it with `$resultObj->max_id`

Comment: As I don't know how `$wpdb->get_results()` actually works, I'm just guessing that this would do the job (thus why it's not an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
SELECT id FROM work_carousels ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, this code works

```
<?php
$max_id = $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT MAX(id) FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'work_carousels' );
```

More about `$wpdb->get_var()` here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/